# Result of terminal command as a command line arguments for a c++ file

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal

For example if i have a terminal command like this 
`$ hostname -I` this will as a result print your ip as a string
to the terminal.
 I want to use the result of this command as the argv[1] argument for my c++ executable. Is there any way I can do that

Comment: @Holt, @Branko Simovic I think this question requires specifying before marking it as duplicated with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c-using-posix Do you want to know how to invoke command from the C++ code or how to redirect the output of `hostname -I` to your program as the first argument, like in: `./my_program $(hostname -I)`?

Comment: @shycha You're right, this is not at all a duplicate, I completely misread the end of the question... Seems clear to me now that what OP want is `./my_program $(hostname -I)`.

Comment: Then it is off topic here and should be asked on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or as it is generic on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Yes, your probably right. If so, I was too fast with answering. Can you/someone delete my answer? The tag is also wrong -- this is the reason I've read it.

@Holt Besides I think I also noticed a small problem with commenting on possibly duplicated question. But I'll need to look for some duplicated question to  confirm it.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not specific enough. However...

1) If you want to invoke the particular command directly from the C++ code, then follow [How to execute a command and get output of command within C++ using POSIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c-using-posix) as Holt suggested.

2) If you want to invoke your program with the output of `hostname -I`, then try:

```
./my_program $(hostname -I)
```

or

```
./my_program `hostname -I`
```